# Is DDR4 RAM compatible in a DDR3 RAM slot?

Tags: memory

I'm looking to get a RAM upgrade for my SONY VAIO VPCEH25FM. If I get DDR4, is it compatible with a DDR3 slot?

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2296287/ddr4-slots-motherboards-reverse-compatible-ddr3.html

They say it's different slots

Comment: Have you checked the manual? Does it say that DDR4 is supported?

Comment: No, I got it 3 years ago and I threw away the manual immediately

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, DDR3 and DDR4 are not cross compatible.  The physical sockets are different among other things like input voltage, pin count, etc.  See the picture below for a full size DIMM, which would be similar to a SODIMM.

[image: DIMM Slots are different]

Comment: how does DDR3L factor in? how does it compare with DDR3 and DDR4?

Comment: @nyxee: See e.g. [What does multiple voltage on RAM memory mean? It says DDR3 1.5V, 1.35V](https://superuser.com/questions/1366136/what-does-multiple-voltage-on-ram-memory-mean-it-says-ddr3-1-5v-1-35v?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

For **nyxee's** question, DDR3L is different from DDR3 and DDR4 as it can work on a voltage range. The DDR3L RAM consumes lesser voltage compared to the DDR3.
DDR3L is a dual voltage capable memory SoDIMM, which supports operation at both 1.5V and 1.35V.DDR3 works on 1.5v only while DDR4 consumes 1.2v only.DDR3 RAM uses a 240-pin connector, while DDR4 RAM uses a 288-pin connector.
For more information go through this [link.](https://www.windowscentral.com/four-big-differences-between-ddr3-and-ddr4-ram)