# What does multiple voltage on RAM memory mean? It says DDR3 1.5V, 1.35V

Tags: memory

Running PerformanceTest9 i notice this information on the RAM memory tab:
4GB DDR3 1.5V, 1.35V

Why does it report both 1,5 Volt and 1,35 Volt at the same time? Does it mean that my memory supports any of those voltages? I believed my memory was DDR3L (L is for low voltage 1.35), but now I'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DDR3L is a dual voltage capable memory DIMM, which supports operation
>   at both 1.5V and 1.35V. DDR3L is also pin-compatible with DDR3.
>
> DDR3 is a single voltage capable memory DIMM, which supports 1.5V
>   operation only.

Source: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/373090/Ram+Upgrade:+can+I+use+DDR3L+instead+of+DDR3

Comment: I understand then, that my memory (as described on the screen-shot) is actually DDR3L. Great!

Comment: Just searching on google on the model number I found the specification at Hynix web site: https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3+SDRAM&srnm=HMT451S6AFR8A&rk=20&rc=module
And they state the same thing: 1.35V but backward Compatible with 1.5V DDR3.